# Is a delete statement rolledback on Redshift when cancelled

Tags: database, amazon-redshift

Want know if a cancelled delete statement on Redshift is rolledback. First I perform count on a table.

```
database=# select count(*) from table_name;
=> 760153276
```

I then cancel a delete statement after it has started.

```
database=#delete from table_name;
Ctrl + c
=> ^CCancel request sent
=> ERROR:  Query (89530) cancelled on user's request
```

After I did another count and records appears to be the same. Does this mean it is rolledback?

```
database=# select count(*) from table_name;
=> 760153276
```

Comment: Yes; statements have an implicit transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's true. But Amazon in its document doesn't want you to rely on issuing **Cancel** statements to ensure rollbacks.

[Amazon Documentation on Cancelling a query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cancel_query.html)